# Custom build rules for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, build-process

I have a Java project that uses some autogenerated source code. This source code is produced by a command-line tool --- Bison, actually --- from a special source file.

I would like a way to have the Java source automatically regenerated whenever necessary when I press the 'build' button in Eclipse. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Normally I'd integrate this into the project makefile, but of course this is Java, and it doesn't use makefiles. I've looked at ant, but ant seems rather hostile to traditional command-line tools. I know something *like* this is possible with the built-in Eclipse builder because the Android development kit does it; so what is it doing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right-click the Project, select `Properties > Builders > New ... > Program`.

There you can select a command line tool that will be run whenever the project is built.

---

For completeness: this is an Eclipse-only solution. I would recommend you to use a build system instead of plain Eclipse. Both Maven and Ant integrate nicely with Eclipse (Maven through [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/), Ant through the same Builder mechanism as above), possibly others as well.

With Maven, you would use [`exec:exec`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html) ([usage](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html)).

With Ant you would use the [`<Exec>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task.

Comment: It looks like the above options run the command unconditionally, which isn't what I want --- I only want to run the tool when the input file changes. Given that this kind of thing is the very heart and soul of a build system, surely Eclipse supports it somehow?

Comment: @David My guess is that you'd have to create a shell script or so that does the check for last-modified against a cache file before calling your executable. Or perhaps one of the restrictions you can apply in the "Build Options" tab is right for you.

Comment: Sigh. What is this, CP/M? Can all 1GB of Eclipse really not do something that half-arsed Unixoids in the 80s were doing as a matter of course? In fact, I now have an ant script that unconditionally calls bison and jflex as part of the build process, and a build is fast enough that always regenerating the source isn't a problem, but... just... sheesh. That's all. Anyway, thanks very much.