# How do I make Eclipse/ADT honor the nocompress tags I added to build.xml?

Tags: android, ant, android-resources, eclipse-adt

#### In a nutshell

I need the Eclipse APK auto-build functionality to use approximately the same build settings the ant command line version.

#### The longer version

There has been a moderate amount of discussion about how to package an asset or resource into an APK without compression. The solutions I've seen involve using an extension like .mp3 that isn't compressed or adding a new tag to the build.xml like `<nocompress extension="pak" />` for *.pak files.

For various reasons that aren't important, the mp3-route isn't possible for this project. I'm ok with the build.xml changes, but Eclipse appears to have its own APK build process that doesn't use the Android-SDK's build.xml. As a result, the pak-files are still compressed.

How do I make Eclipse either use the regular ant build files or change the configuration to mirror the same no-compress settings?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you put these files in your values/raw directory instead of the values/asset directory?

Comment: I could, but the same compression issue persists in either place.

Comment: I don't think that when you are reading from the raw directory, you are reading a compressed copy of it's contents. Maybe I don't understand your question.

Comment: With the exception of certain file extensions like mp3, files in both the <proj>/assets and <proj>/res/raw folder are still compressed. You can verify that with any Zip-archive viewer. The compression ratio should be 0% for an uncompressed file. Additionally, the file-descriptor functions like AssetManager.openFd() will fail on a compressed file.

Comment: Okay, you are correct. I was using png files which are on the list to not compress. There doesn't seem to be any real documentation on that nocompress tag... voting up the question.

Answer (score 0):

A) You can run Ant build from eclipse:

1. In eclipse add Ant View: Click Windows > Show View> Ant
2. In Ant view click on Add build file icon and link your build.xml.
3. Now Ant view will show ant targets. Run the taget you wish

B) Try this [Custom build rules for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469524/custom-build-rules-for-eclipse)