# Eclipse: How to write the current time to a file as part of every build?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have an app. The app has an about screen. I want to show the build date and time on this screen.

To do this I want to run a program that writes the current time to a file and places it in the `res/` folder before the normal build process starts. The program is run from a jar.

How do I run this program from part of the build process in Eclipse?

Ant seems like the best way to go about this. Does Eclipse already use ant as part of its build/debug process? Can I modify an existing file that the project already uses or do I need to download and run ant externally?

**EDIT**: What I want to be able to do is run this task as part of me pressing the debug button up the top. I don't want to have to run two separate commands as this would defeat the whole purpose of the build time being written to file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your [own builders](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-93_project_builder.htm), which can be based on ant if you want. These builders can be run as part of the Eclipse compiling process to ensure the behavior that you described.

Comment: Thanks, I found a great succinct answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469524/custom-build-rules-for-eclipse) that explains the exact process needed to create a new builder.

Answer (score 0):

1. Does Eclipse already use ant as part of its build/debug process?
   Yes, Eclipse recognize ant scripts and possible to use for build/debug.
2. Can I modify an existing file that the project already uses or do I need to download and run ant externally? You can run your ant task from external process/eclipse when building. Ant task should be able to modify the expected resource file.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I wonder if Eclipse is suitable to act as a build tools for release (I only use it as an IDE and I believe that's its strength).  I suggest using other build tools (like Maven and Ant) and such requirement can be easily achieved.

Just to remind that, even you have Maven/Ant, you can trigger their build process in Eclipse.