# How to customize commands on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, command

How do I customize the commands to compile and execute a Java app on Eclipse? I have to change the normal commands in order to compile and execute my application.

Thanks

Comment: Customize in what way? Be more specific about your requirements.

Comment: Suppose that I have a program called Hello.java.
After compiled, eclipse executes the program running "java Hello".
I want that eclipse executes instead of it, this command "mpirun -np 4 java Hello"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you use combine key Alt X + Alt J to execute build-in compile tool (which will run the main method, if you've configed correctly.

In the case you want to use other compile/execute tool, press f10 to open prefrences, go to generals/Keys, to the right is the windows where you customize your hot key.

For example, I want to bring up run configuration windows, filter word "run...", then select the command, in the binding below, press "Alt+Shift+X, C", select When: Windows, then apply, OK. after that, whenever in eclipse, I press Alt+Shift+X + C, the run configurations open.

EDIT: I'm not sure about mpi, but as you asked how to run with mpi, I've done a research around:

[Configure MPI in Eclipse](https://jaqoup.wordpress.com/2009/05/10/configure-mpi-programs-in-eclipse/)

[Run MPI Programs in Eclipse with 1-Click](http://geekeeway.blogspot.com/2010/10/run-mpi-programs-in-eclipse-with-1.html)

You can check it yourself.

Comment: Ok got it, but it doesn't change the running command.
Suppose that I have a program called Hello.java. Normally, after compiled, eclipse executes the program running "java Hello". I want that eclipse executes instead of it, the command "mpirun -np 4 java Hello". How can I change this configuration? Thanks

Comment: In this case, it's not about key binding command, but rather run/build configuration. This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469524/custom-build-rules-for-eclipse

Comment: Ok. After right-clicking on the project I do Properties > Builders > New ... > Program but after that I don't know how to customize it.
I would like to customize the compiling and exucuting operations. 
I would like to compile in this way: <pre>javac -cp Hello.java</code>
and I would like to execute in this way:  mpirun -np 4 java Hello

Where Hello.java is the name of my java app

Comment: Yes I need something like the lasts 2 links you posted but for Java. I tried to follow those steps on my eclipse but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For run in run configuration you can set all parameters. For build flag I think it will be faster to create some ant,maven script.

Comment: How do I set all parameters? I don't know how to set into eclipse the command to run mpi, like this one: "mpirun -np 4 java Hello"

Comment: I didn't see that this command is before java :) . Generally you want to run mpirun that is running environment itself. Fastest way I think to create build, running script and use this script in eclipse. Or you can try install C++ plugin for eclipse, and there is plugin or option for mpirun. Then you can try :run -> external tools end will be option to launch configuration for mpirun.